# Creating a diagonal Background effect with a repeat background

Tags: jquery, effects

I'm really on the side trying to figure out out to make this happen.

I have a repeating background image:
lets say:

```
body{
    background: url(img/triangles.jpg) repeat;
}
```

That BG image is:
 width: 113px;
 height: 183px;

What I want to do is to make that background grow until if occupies the browser window and if the user srcools down it keeps on growing...

The example of the desired effect: 
http://aviathemes.com/aviaslider/?slider=diagonal-blocks -> The diagonal block effects.

Comment: You might need body { height: 100%; width: 100% }

Comment: the above css should make the image cover the whole of the body background, if you have stated a height of 100% on the body as gavin has said, then the background will cut off where the scroll starts as the body will only be as high as the viewport

Comment: What I want is how to make the effect working, with Jquery/JS, like the example above